# jQuery Visibility Visibile Not Working In WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, visibility

So I'm trying to add a simple jQuery function in WordPress on page to show a hidden div when a specific anchor's class is clicked.

```
<script>
jQuery('.btn more').click(function() {
.submenu("visibility", "visible");
});
</script>
```

This isn't working at all though. I know that WordPress doesn't like the $ call for jQuery so I've used jQuery itself.

The corresponding HTML I'm targeting is as follows. (Haven't included all the HTML here for ease)

```
<a class="btn more" href="#">Learn More</a>
<div class="submenu" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

Have I done something massively stupid with the jQuery or is this something to do with WordPress? I'd just appreciate it if someone even let me know if this code should work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
jQuery('.btn more').click(function() {
    JQuery('.submenu').css("visibility", "visible");
});
</script>
```